# HLS video streamming and chat message synchronization

Tags: video-streaming, http-live-streaming

We're using the following architecture to build a live stream / chat application for mobile devices:

- Video Live Stream: WoWza API to create and join streams using HLS protocol
- Live Message System: Rest API backed by RabbitMQ

Because of various factors there's a "natural" delay between the host video stream and viewers actualy seeing the video.
The problem is that chat messages are delivered instantly so video and messages become total out of sync.

What would be a good strategy for keeping video and messages synchronized among viewers?

Comment: Are you looking for ways to get the latency down? Or strategies for dealing with the fact that there is latency? How many seconds of latency are you seeing? 15 seconds is pretty common among services like Twitch, and is pretty acceptable from an audience perspective with the host responding audibly. If the host needs to be in chat also, that's hard.

Answer (score 1):

Technically, you can use timed metadata in HLS:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/previous/media-services-specifications-live-timed-metadata#32--apple-hls-delivery
and delay your chat messages on the client side accordingly, but then your chat turns into a chat with remote galaxy, with huge delays between messages.
So the practicality of such a solution is zero, considering, in addition, that HLS latency is not controllable and can fluctuate considerably around its average value.

So your real solution is to move away from HLS and use WebRTC.